# Solving and verification of : $\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \cos (\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y}) \boldsymbol{x}^{T}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, vectors, solution-verification

I am trying to simplify an expression and would like to ask if my approach is correct and also could I simplify this expression further. If so what would I use? I am doing a bit of self-studying here so I must apologize if this is trivial.

**Question**:

Say $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ find the explicit expression:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \cos (\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y}) \boldsymbol{x}^{T} 
\end{align*}

**My Answer**:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \cos (\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y}) \boldsymbol{x}^{T} = -\boldsymbol{y} \sin(\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y})\boldsymbol{x}^{T}
\end{align*}

1. Is the answer correct?
2. Can I simplify this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that:

$$\frac{d}{dy} \cos(xy) = -x\sin(xy) \neq -y\sin(xy).$$

Therefore, in your case, the right derivative is:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \cos (\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y}) \boldsymbol{x}^{T} = -\boldsymbol{x} \sin(\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y})\boldsymbol{x}^{T}
\end{align*}$$

Since $\sin(\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y})$ is a number, then you can write this as:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{y}} \cos (\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y}) \boldsymbol{x}^{T} = -\sin(\boldsymbol{x}^{T}\boldsymbol{y})\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{x}^{T}
\end{align*}$$